# Get text from series of elements to an array using cypress JS

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to get comma separated text from series of `<th>` elements in a table row. I tried to use element`.each()` method for 3 nested loops from Cypress and it was super slow and was throwing error (`cy.click()` failed because this element is detached from the DOM.) sporadically in different test levels (Sometimes passed without any issue). I assume this might be due to large number of unnecessary loops to capture values with the above mentioned method.

Code

```
const verifyLeaderBoard = () => {
    let ClassName;
    let clickedElement;
    LeaderBoard.elementCollections('rows').each(($rowelements, indexrow, $list) => {
        cy.wrap($rowelements).invoke('attr', 'class').then((TeeTimeTableRowClass) => {
            ClassName = TeeTimeTableRowClass || 'Empty';
            cy.wait(10).then(() => {
                if ((ClassName.indexOf('accordion-toggle') !== -1)) {
                    cy.wait(5).then(() => {
                        LeaderBoard.inputFields('playerserach').focus().wait(100);
                    }).then(() => {
                        cy.wrap($rowelements).click({ force: true }).wait(1000);
                        clickedElement = $rowelements;
                    })
                } else if ((ClassName.indexOf('hidden-row-wrap') !== -1)) {
                    cy.wait(10).then(() => {
                        cy.wrap($rowelements).xpath('.//div[@class="table-responsive-xl"]//table[@class="table score-table"]//thead//tr')
                            .each(($HoleandParElement, index, $list) => {
                                cy.wrap($HoleandParElement).xpath('.//th')
                                    .each(($HoleandParElementtabledata, index, $list) => {
                                        cy.wrap($HoleandParElementtabledata).invoke('text')
                                            .then(texts => {
                                                console.log(texts)
                                            })
                                    })
                            })
                    }).then(() => {
                        cy.wrap(clickedElement).click({ force: true }).wait(100);
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

Error

[image]

Its working fine without the error if I just skip final element`.each()` as follows.

Code

```
const verifyLeaderBoard = () => {
    let ClassName;
    let clickedElement;
    LeaderBoard.elementCollections('rows').each(($rowelements, indexrow, $list) => {
        cy.wrap($rowelements).invoke('attr', 'class').then((TeeTimeTableRowClass) => {
            ClassName = TeeTimeTableRowClass || 'Empty';
            cy.wait(10).then(() => {
                if ((ClassName.indexOf('accordion-toggle') !== -1)) {
                    cy.wait(5).then(() => {
                        LeaderBoard.inputFields('playerserach').focus().wait(100);
                    }).then(() => {
                        cy.wrap($rowelements).click({ force: true }).wait(1000);
                        clickedElement = $rowelements;
                    })
                } else if ((ClassName.indexOf('hidden-row-wrap') !== -1)) {
                    cy.wait(10).then(() => {
                        cy.wrap($rowelements).xpath('.//div[@class="table-responsive-xl"]//table[@class="table score-table"]//thead//tr')
                            .each(($HoleandParElement, index, $list) => {
                                cy.wrap($HoleandParElement).invoke('text')
                                    .then(texts => {
                                        console.log(texts)
                                    })
                            })
                    }).then(() => {
                        cy.wrap(clickedElement).click({ force: true }).wait(100);
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    })
}
```

But in this case all the data in separate `<th>` tags are merged without a single space (Not possible to split by a string)

[image]

I'm searching for a solution to capture all the texts in `<th>` tags with a special character to divide each value.

HTML Structure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used bellow line to collect all inner text to an array.

```
Cypress._.map(Cypress.$.makeArray($els), 'innerText')
```

Following code with the above solution was used to generate the array which contains all inner texts in `<th>` tags and this was must faster than using `.each` for the bulk of elements.

```
const verifyLeaderBoard = () => {
    let ClassName;
    let clickedElement;
    LeaderBoard.elementCollections('rows').each(($rowelements, indexrow, $list) => {
        cy.wrap($rowelements).invoke('attr', 'class').then((TeeTimeTableRowClass) => {
            ClassName = TeeTimeTableRowClass || 'Empty';
            cy.wait(10).then(() => {
                if ((ClassName.indexOf('accordion-toggle') !== -1)) {
                    cy.wait(5).then(() => {
                        LeaderBoard.inputFields('playerserach').focus().wait(100);
                    }).then(() => {
                        cy.wrap($rowelements).click({ force: true }).wait(1000);
                        clickedElement = $rowelements;
                    });
                } else if ((ClassName.indexOf('hidden-row-wrap') !== -1)) {
                    cy.wait(10).then(() => {
                        cy.wrap($rowelements).xpath('.//div[@class="table-responsive-xl"]//table[@class="table score-table"]//thead//tr')
                            .each(($HoleandParElement, index, $list) => {
                                cy.wrap($HoleandParElement).xpath('.//th').then(($els) => {
                                    // jQuery => Array => get "innerText" from each
                                    let elementsArray = Cypress._.map(Cypress.$.makeArray($els), 'innerText');
                                    console.log('elementsArray');
                                    console.log([...elementsArray.entries()]);
                                  });
                            });
                    }).then(() => {
                        cy.wrap(clickedElement).click({ force: true }).wait(100);
                    });
                };
            });
        });
    });
};
```